# Does cluster endpoint of AWS RDS not allow CNAME?

Tags: dns, amazon-rds

I registered a cluster url for a specific RDS as CNAME through Route53. When I look up records through `nslookup`, It's expressed as expected, but I can't connect to database. Was it intentionally blocked by AWS?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you connect to the rds instance using its ip?

Comment: I can access through the existing RDS URL, which is the target of CNAME records.